# Paypal single cart multi recurring plan checkout

Tags: laravel, paypal, cart, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I am using paypal payment gateway in my laravel project and met one issue.
Some of my products are one time payment, and some of them are recurring payment.
So if customer puts them in  cart together, is it possible to check out them at one time?

```
Package A - $50.00
Package B - $20.00/a month
Package C - $30.00/a week
```

Above items are in cart.
And how can we checkout it at one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware it's not possible. You could create a single custom subscription plan on the fly with a setup_fee that totals up to the one-time payments, but that is messy.

Comment: Well, then isn't there any solution for this?
I found one thing but I think there will be better solution. After one agreement is accepted , I redirected to paypal for other agreement forcely. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. What solution are you using for multi agreements?

Comment: https://snipboard.io/5myZvo.jpg    In foreach, I put approval url in session and after execute each payment, redirect to next approval url.     https://snipboard.io/jqfYlz.jpg

Comment: Ick. Well, I would recommend using zero redirects (none at all) and switching to the new subscriptions API with smart payment buttons. Then the approval can happen in the in-context window, without leaving your site.  See the "paypal.buttons" invocation with a plan_id here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#4-create-a-subscription

Comment: HI @preston-phx, I heard express checkout can handle up to 10 recurring profiles at one time. Can I do this using express checkout api?

Comment: That API is two generations out of date; I do not recommend touching it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK
This is also out of date? 
They told to use https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK.
But I think v2 checkout api doesn't get full functions as much as v1.
For example, billing plan, subscription...

Comment: PayPal-PHP-SDK is out of date, yes. It doesn't support the latest subscriptions API.  Checkout-PHP-SDK has no support for subscriptions at all.  For the current subscriptions you need to use a direct API integration (no SDK)

Comment: Could you please show me the current subscription link in Paypal doc?
Is the current subscription different a lot from previous Paypal-PHP-SDK's one?
I am confusing about Paypal API. There are too many api docs. :) 
Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, How about this? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/
Is this the old version?

Comment: That is the API reference